# How do you display a floating point value, with decimals, in LLDB

Tags: xcode, lldb

In gdb, I can use the print command to display a floating point or double variable, and I get a value with several decimal places. The equivalent command in LLDB, expr, seems to round/truncate the value and only show the whole number portion. The format string documentation for LLDB is more than a little obtuse. How do I display a double precision or single precision floating point local variable, including the decimal portion?

if foo = 3.1415926, then

expr foo

displays

foo = 3

Not very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the expr command. It's cumbersome, but it works:

```
(lldb) expr (int) printf("%f \n",foo)
3.14159
(lldb)
```

Comment: Thx. That solves it. Why doesn't "expr foo" do it? The gdb expression "p foo" gives me the decimal, but "expr foo" does not. Seems like the default display format for a floating point expression should show the floating point value. Also, do you know of a way to change the display format of an LLDB expression, without having to resort to invoking printf? Something like "expr %f foo"?